# Why parallel std::for_each return void

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I am reading [C++17 in detail](https://www.cppindetail.com/data/cpp17indetail-sample.pdf).
There is a description for **std::for_each** below, in this book:

> In the serial version of for_each, the version that was available before C++17 >you get a unary
> function as a return value from the algorithm.
> Returning such an object is not possible in a parallel version, as the order >of invocations is indeterminate.

I still understand, why parallel **std::for_each** can not return the functor **f**. Although the order of invocations is indeterminate, parallel **for_each** block to wait invoke finish.When every parallel operation finish, returning the **f** is seemed ok.

Comment: That is truly weird. Fortunately, it seems that C++20 had it covered (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: @PsychoX I don't get what you mean. C++20 only adds  `constexpr` declaration to the non-parallel overload.

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind returning the functor is to allow the functor to accumulate state across successive calls. The accumulated state could be accessed through the returned copy.

Accumulation requires serial access to the accumulated state, which would defeat the purpose of parallel execution. Essentially, each thread of execution will get a copy of the function object and their state is not shared.

The standard has following note:

> [Note: Does not return a copy of its Function parameter, since parallelization may not permit efficient
>   state accumulation. — end note]

Comment: Thank for your answer. But in my opinion:
1.To make accessing to the accumulated state atomic is not wrong, although it may be reduce parallelization efficiency. Side effects are covered user may be more reasonable.
2.May be the functor be used to implement other purpose that different from the srouce purpose, or not involving accumulated state, by user. So keeping interface conformance may be more reasonable.

Comment: 1. Sure, but the key word here is **efficiency** 2. Conforming to the same return type would be a bad design when the returned value has no use.